# Problem using `flake8` for linting on Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, flake8, linter

I've been unsuccessfully trying to use the `SublimeLinter-flake8` on my Xubuntu laptop. I have Python 3.7.7 installed through the Anaconda distribution, as well as the `flake8` package. I'm also using the Anaconda IDE plugin for Sublime Text 3, with Anaconda's linting turned off.

But I keep getting the same error message whenever I type some Python code in:

```
SublimeLinter: #1 flake8 <untitled 25> ERROR:
=============================================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/srdjan/anaconda3/bin/flake8", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('flake8==3.7.7', 'console_scripts', 'flake8')()
  File "/home/srdjan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 484, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/srdjan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2714, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/srdjan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2332, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/srdjan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2338, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/home/srdjan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flake8/main/cli.py", line 2, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
  File "/home/srdjan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/typing.py", line 1347, in <module>
    class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
  File "/home/srdjan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/typing.py", line 1003, in __new__
    self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry
```

Strangely enough, I was having somewhat similar problems when I was using `SublimeLinter-pycodestyle` and `SublimeLinter-pyflakes`, where `pyflakes` would keep throwing these weird error messages. I was never able to get it to work.

Should I perhaps uninstall `pycodestyle` and `pyflakes` from my laptop, now that I have `flake8` and its accompanying `SublimeLinter-flake8` plugin?